# Table notes not showing \textnotes

Tags: tables, threeparttable

The symbol I added as notes \textdagger and \textasteriskcentered does not appear in the table or in the table footnote.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Resultado das simulações para 32 amostras/ciclo para energização de banco de transformadores sob carga}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccccccccccc|}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Caso}                                                                      & \multicolumn{11}{c|}{32 amostras/ciclo}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \cline{2-12} 
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Método}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Fechamento da chave}} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Bloqueio do relé}                                                                                                                                                                                 & \multirow{3}{*}{Desempenho} \\ \cline{4-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                     & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Ângulo de carregamento}                                                                                                                                                                           &                             \\ \cline{4-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{15}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{30}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{45}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{60}  &                             \\ \hline
\multirow{31}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}S\\ O\\ B\\ \\ C\\ A\\ R\\ G\\ A\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{8}{*}{MPL}}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,2}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multirow{8}{*}{100\%}      \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,202083}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,204166}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,20625}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,208333}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,210416}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,2125}                               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,214583}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{2-12} 
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{8}{*}{MFAAFO}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,2}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multirow{8}{*}{100\%}      \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,202083}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,204166}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,20625}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,208333}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,210416}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,2125}                               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,214583}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{2-12} 
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{8}{*}{MCSLFO}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,2}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multirow{8}{*}{54,16\%}    \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,202083}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,204166}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,20625}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,208333}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,210416}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textdagger}} &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,2125}                               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,214583}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  &                             \\ \cline{2-12} 
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{7}{*}{MGMA}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,2}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multirow{8}{*}{93,23\%}    \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,202083}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,204166}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,20625}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,208333}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,210416}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X\textasteriskcentered}  &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,2125}                               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \cline{3-11}
                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0,214583}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X}   &                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}


\smallskip
\small
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[\textasteriskcentered] Não identificou \textit{inrush} em uma das fases.
\item[\textdagger] Não identificou \textit{inrush} em duas fases.

\end{tablenotes}

\smallskip
\centering
Fonte: Autor
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You have failed to encase the `\caption` statement and the `tabular` and `tablenotes` environments in a `threeparttable` environment.

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: It's not enough to load the `threeparttable` package. You also have to encase the `\caption` statement, the `tabular` environment, and the `tablenotes` environment in a `threeparttable` environment.

Comment: The fact that the left-hand edge of the `tablenotes` environment shown in your screenshot isn't aligned withe the left-hand edge of the `tabular` environment is a dead give-away that your code is not actually employing a `threeparttable` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to load the `threeparttable` package in the preamble. You also have to encase the three formal components of a `threepartable` structure -- the `\caption` statement, the `tabular` environment, and the `tablenotes` environment -- in a `threeparttable` environment.

To improve both the maintainability of the code and the legibility of the output, you should try to declutter your code, e.g,. by getting rid of almost all (entirely useless) `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrappers and by getting rid of (or, at least, commenting out all `\cline{3-11}` directives. Aligning the numbers in column 3 on their decimal markers would also be appreciated by your readers. Finally, consider replacing the `X` letters with `\times`, also for a less heavy-handed "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or 'brazilian' ?
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\usepackage{dcolumn} % for 'D' column type
\newcolumntype{d}[2]{D{,}{,}{#1}} % align numbers on comma (decimal marker)

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
% handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\tnoteA{\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}
\newcommand\tnoteB{\tnote{\textdagger}}
\newcommand\XX{$\times$}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \smash[b] macro
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Resultado das simulações para 32 amostras\slash ciclo 
       para energização de banco de transformadores sob carga}

\begin{tabular}{| c | l d{1,6} *{10}{c} |}
\hline
Caso  & \multicolumn{11}{c|}{32 amostras/ciclo} \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & Método 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytab{Fechamento\\ da chave}} 
 & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Bloqueio do relé} 
 & Desempenho \\ %\cline{4-11}
 & & & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Ângulo de carregamento} & \\  \cline{4-11}
 & & & 0 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 30 & 45 & 60 & \\ 
\hline
\multirow{32}{*}{%
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} S\\O\\B\\ \\C\\A\\R\\G\\A \end{tabular}} 
& \multirow{8}{*}{MPL} 
    & 0,2      & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{100\%} \\ 
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & \multirow{8}{*}{MFAAFO}
    & 0,2      & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{100\%} \\ 
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & \multirow{8}{*}{MCSLFO}
    & 0,2      & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{54,16\%} \\  
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\  
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & \multirow{8}{*}{MGMA}   
    & 0,2      & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{93,23\%} \\  
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX & \XX & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\  
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\  
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\small
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[\textasteriskcentered] Não identificou \textit{inrush} em uma das fases.
\item[\textdagger] Não identificou \textit{inrush} em duas fases.
\end{tablenotes}

\smallskip\small
Fonte: Autor

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `talltblr`, which is `tabularray` equivalent for `threeparttable` package:

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or 'brazilian' ?

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Resultado das simulações para 32 amostras\slash ciclo
           para energização de banco de transformadores sob carga},
  label = {tab:???},
note{*}       = {Não identificou \textit{inrush} em uma das fases.},
note{$\dag$}  = {Não identificou \textit{inrush} em duas fases.},
remark{Fonte} = {Autor}
                ]{vline{1-4,8,12,13},
                  colspec = { c l S[table-format=1.6]  *{8}{Q[c,mode=math]} r},
                  row{1-3} = {guard, mode=text}
                }
    \toprule
Caso    &   \SetCell[c=11]{c}   32 amostras/ciclo   
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
    \cmidrule{2-12}
        & Método
            & {Fechamento\\ da chave}
                &   \SetCell[c=8]{c}    {Bloqueio do relé\\ Ângulo de carregamento}
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & Desempenho    \\ 
    \cmidrule{4-11}
    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 30 & 45 & 60 &              \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=32]{c}  {S\\O\\B\\~ \\C\\A\\R\\G\\A}
    &   \SetCell[r=8]{l}   MPL 
        & 0,2       & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &
                                    \SetCell[r=8]{l}   \qty{100}{\%}    \\
    &   & 0,202083  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &   \\
    &   & 0,204166  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &   \\
    &   & 0,20625   & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &   \\
    &   & 0,208333  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &   \\
    &   & 0,210416  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &   \\
    &   & 0,2125    & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &   \\
    &   & 0,214583  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &   \\
    \midrule
    &   \SetCell[r=8]{l}   MFAAFO 
    & 0,2      & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &
                                    \SetCell[r=8]{l}   \qty{100}{\%}    \\
    &   & 0,202083  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &   \\
    &   & 0,204166  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,20625   & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,208333  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,210416  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,2125    & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,214583  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    \midrule
    &   \SetCell[r=8]{l}   MCSLFO 
        & 0,2       & \times\TblrNote{*}   & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}
                    & \times\TblrNote{*}   & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}
                    &   \SetCell[r=8]{l}   \qty{54,16}{\%} \\
    &   & 0,202083  & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}
        & \times\TblrNote{*}       & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}
        & \times\TblrNote{*}       &               \\
    &   & 0,204166  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}
        & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}
        & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  &               \\
    &   & 0,20625           & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}
        & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}
        & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  &               \\
    &   & 0,208333          & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}
        & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}
        & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  &               \\
    &   & 0,210416          & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}
        & \times\TblrNote{\dag}   & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}  & \times\TblrNote{\dag}
        & \times\TblrNote{\dag}   &               \\
    &   & 0,2125            & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,214583          & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}
        & \times\TblrNote{*}   & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}
        & \times\TblrNote{*}   & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \\
    \midrule
    &   \SetCell[r=8]{l}   MGMA
        & 0,2               & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times &
                                \SetCell[r=8]{l}   \qty{93,23}{\%} \\
    &   & 0,202083 & \times & \times & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}
        & \times\TblrNote{*}   & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}
                &           \\
    &   & 0,204166 & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,20625  & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,208333 & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,210416 & \times & \times\TblrNote{*} & \times\TblrNote{*}  & \times\TblrNote{*}
        & \times\TblrNote{*}& \times\TblrNote{*} & \times\TblrNote{*}  & {\times*}  & \\
    &   & 0,2125   & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    &   & 0,214583 & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \times & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note: used is `tabularray` package version 2022C.

[image]